# how to remove Listview Item from listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i want to delete listview item On click 
i have created remove methode TO Deleted ..
But When I click On Button It Only like Just Refreshed Not Deleted That Item 
please Tell ME Where I m Doing Wrong

```
Button yes=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.yes);
        yes.setTag(position);
        yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                UserProfile u=new UserProfile();

                resultp.remove(data.get(position));
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
                 Toast.makeText(context, "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

here is my Code i m using On Button click 
in this 
resultp is

```
 HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and data Is Array list

i will appreciate your answer

Comment: Open _www.google.com_ then type **"how to remove listview item in android"**. The first thing you will see is a question from stackoverflow link. Open that and solve your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must the line

```
resultp.remove(position);
```

and then

```
resultp.notifyDataSetChanged();
```